Title of the movie (French or Spanish or Foreign) with Jewish characters
I watched this movie several years ago on IFC movie channel. To the best of my recollection, the scene takes place approximately from 1600s to late 1800s, because people use horses and carriages to travel. The movie is either French or Spanish but definitely foreign. Most likely the movie is French. I watched it with subtitles.  
I don’t remember the whole movie and possibly did not watch it from the very beginning so I will tell what I can remember.
The movie is about a woman who has an abusive husband. The woman probably is Jewish. They have two children a boy and a girl. The boy is approximately 11-14 years old. The girl is 7-12 years old. The girl is younger than her brother. 
This woman has a friend or a relative who is also a Rabbi having a Judaic-mystical or kabalistic powers.
At one point and while the husband is not home, the wife tries to run away from her husband. With the help of the Rabbi they place the children into a big wooden chest to hide them and to place the chest onto a carriage. However, when they’re about to leave, husband arrives home. The children are inside the chest. The chest is on the floor in the entrance room and is closed. Seeing the situation, the husband goes upstairs to check on the children. At the same time the Rabbi, having these special powers, says something/prays and screams out the prayer. Mysteriously, as the husband opens the door to the children’s room, the children are physically relocated to their room and are now seating on the floor.    
Later on that same day or other day, the wife gives her husband sleeping drug while having a conversation with him. She either adds it to the alcohol which husband drinks or gives it to him separately. When he is finally asleep, she takes her children and leaves going to the Rabbi’s houses. I think the Rabbi lives in another town…
[The woman is afraid that her husband will find her, take children, and punish her. I also think that she was afraid or could not get a divorce. Also, I need to mention here that someone else was living with the woman and her husband at the time. I could be wrong, but that person was also a woman. She is possibly related to the husband – sister of the husband? -].
When at the Rabbi’s house, the boy (a son of the woman) encounters another boy approximately 13-16years old. I think he is either the son/relative or a pupil of the Rabbi. He is blond. I also think his name was Yakov. Yakov also has some powers. The boy encounters Yakov either in the basement or in another room. Yakov either says something to the boy or talks to himself or makes some kind of moves while in some kind of trance or half asleep. While he does his moves probably lying down, another scene takes place in the husband’s house who is still asleep. His, husband's sister does the same moves as the Yakov and either takes a candle or a candle lamp and intentionally (because she aware of him being abusive) or unintentionally - but still under some influence by Yakov - starts a fire in the husband’s house. The house goes in flames, while husband is asleep.   
I tried to find the title to this movie for a long time but could not find it. I really want to watch it again. Any help from anyone is much appreciated. Thank You.  

Ingmar Bergman's Fanny and Alexander, (1982).  It is the mother's friend Isak Jacobi, (Erland Josephson), and his nephew Ismael Retzinsky, (Stina Ekblad), who are Jewish.  The nephew is apparently so intensely magical that he has to be kept locked up.

Emilie asks for a divorce, which Edvard will not consent to; though
  she may desert the marriage, doing so would place the children in his
  custody, including the infant from her recent pregnancy. Meanwhile,
  the rest of the Ekdahl family has begun to worry about their
  condition. When Emilie secretly visits her former mother-in-law,
  Helena (Gunn Wållgren), to explain what happened, their friend Isak
  Jacobi (Erland Josephson), helps smuggle the children from the house.
  They live temporarily with Isak and his nephews in their store.
...
Alexander had fantasized about his stepfather's death while living
  with Isak. Isak's mysterious nephew, Ismael Retzinsky (Stina Ekblad),
  explains that fantasy can become true as he dreams it.
...
After Emilie gets away, Edvard's dying aunt knocks over a gas lamp,
  which sets her bedroom and nightgown on fire. She runs through the
  house in flames to Edvard's room and falls on him. Despite the
  sedative, he is able to get her off him, but dies shortly thereafter.


Thank You! I dreamed watching this movie for years. I watched Ingmar Bergman's The Seventh Seal and The Virgin Spring. I liked his movies and read more about him on Wikipedia to see what other movies he made. Somehow I overlooked Fanny and Alexander
